# rails json - validates acceptance of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

I have a rails app that makes an API that an ionic (angular) app consumes. In my user sign up, I ask users to agree to terms of service before signing up, and have that set in my params in my controller.

The model side looks like this:

```
# agreeing to terms of service
  validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service, on: :create
```

The controller looks like this:

```
def mobile_user_params
    allowed = [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :location, :terms_of_service]
    params.require(:user).permit(allowed)
end
```

and the end result in the params look like this:

```
{"user"=>{"terms_of_service"=>true}, "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"mobile_create", "format"=>"json"}
```

what my problem is, even tho it is returning `{"terms_of_service"=>true}` because I am accepting it, this returns an error message that is:

`errors: {"Terms of Service must be accepted"}`

Does anyone know how I can satisfy this validation? It works when rendering HTML using a checkbox, but on JSON requests I cannot seem to satisfy it.

Any help at all would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look to the [doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_acceptance_of)?

According to:

> :accept - Specifies value that is considered accepted. The default value is a string "1", which makes it easy to relate to an HTML checkbox. This should be set to true if you are validating a database column, since the attribute is typecasted from "1" to true before validation.

I think that you should add: `validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service, accept: true`